# can not delete the funny character "½" in Python 3.9.2

Tags: python, str-replace

#below is the step to delete the funny character "½" in Python version 2.6.6, and it works well.

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

import os,glob

funny=glob.glob('C:\A\Text\*')   #This folder has 10 files, so i use '*' for a loop

for h in funny:
    with open(r'%s' %h, 'r') as infile,open(r'%sN' %h, 'w') as outfile:
        data = infile.read()
        data = data.replace ("13½","13")
        data = data.decode("ascii", "ignore")
        outfile.write(data)
        infile.close()
        outfile.close()
        os.remove(h)
        os.rename(r'%sN' %h,r'%s' %h)
```

but now we upgrade to version 3.9.2, and this can not work, it shows below error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:/A/test.py", line 10, in 
> data = infile.read()
> File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
> return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 10871: character maps to

i searched a lot and there is no **replace** function in new version with that "½", any ideas?

Comment: FYI, `r'%s' %h` is a confusing way to just write `h`.

Comment: It looks as if ```infile.read()``` is causing the error. ```open``` in python takes an optional ```encoding``` keyword. Try setting ```encoding="utf-8"``` and see what happens.

Comment: @Kevin \x9d is not well-defined in UTF-8 either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 3 needs to know which encoding the input file is in.  Per the traceback, it seems to default to cp1252, but clearly that's incorrect. I can find no encoding where this character actually maps to the glyph in your question; see https://tripleee.github.io/8bit/#9d (disclosure: my own resource) for a listing of encodings supported by Python 3.6.8. (Should not have changed much in 3.9.)

Wishing to discard data you don't know how to handle is frequently just a desperate workaround, where the proper solution is to understand what the data represents, and either fix the error at the source if it really is erroneous, or else handle it properly instead of removing it.

But here is a fix for your code.

```py
for h in glob.glob(r'C:\A\Text\*'):
    dest = '%sN' % h
    with open(h, 'r', encoding='latin-1') as infile, open(dest, 'w', encoding='latin-1') as outfile:
        for line in infile:
            line = line.replace("13\x9d", "13")
            outfile.write(line)
    os.remove(h)
    os.rename(dest, h)
```

The Latin-1 encoding may not be exactly correct here, but as long as you are using the same encoding for reading and writing, and all the character codes are defined in that encoding (as they conveniently are in Latin-1) the result should be what you expect.

I also refactored to read a line at a time instead of slurping the entire file into memory; if you have enough RAM it should not matter, but if you might have big files, this should also improve robustness.  If the files are not really text files, perhaps roll back that change (but then you will probably have different problems down the line anyway).